# Uploadify / Uploadifive randomly not uploading individual files (IIS 7.5 server)

Tags: jquery, iis, file-upload, uploadify

I am having trouble getting file uploads to work reliably using both Uploadify and Uploadifive (I have fallback configured when browser does not support Uploadifive).

Most times, all files upload ok to the destination directly. However, randomly, one file in the queue won't appear in the destination directly (all others appear during a multi-file selection). Note 'auto' is set to true.

The 'missing' file will still show visibly in the queue on the page, but won't have been uploaded.

Investigating the POST in Firebug shows most files being sent to the upload script are including both the file data and the token variable. But the single file that doesn't work isn't sending either the file data or the token (POST for that file upload is 0KB).

The behaviour is unfortunately sporadic or at least I can't work out the pattern. If I delete that file from the queue and re-upload it, it works. If I clear the browser cache, refresh the page and try uploading the same set of files at once, all will successfully upload.

The problem occurs across different browsers (IE11, FF).

Server files are being uploaded to is IIS7.5.

It does sometimes happen for a single file as well. E.g. the one file selected will visibly show in queue, but nothing will have been uploaded.

I have added enctype='multipart/form-data' on my  tag

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uploadifive').uploadifive({
        'auto'              :   true,
        'fileSizeLimit'     :   "5GB",
        'formData'          :   { 'token' : '<?php echo $token; ?>' },
        'queueSizeLimit'    :   0,
        'removeCompleted'   :   false,
        'uploadScript'      :   '/assets/transmitdocs_tempuploads/transmitdocs_moveFilesToServer.php',

        'onCancel'          :   function (file) {
                                    deleteFromUploadifyQueue (file.id, file.name);
                                },

        'onUpload'          :   function (file) {
                                    document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').value = "Please wait...";
                                    document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').disabled = 'disabled';
                                },

        'onQueueComplete'   :   function () {
                                document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').value = "Next >";
                                document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').disabled = '';
                            },

        'onFallback'        :   function () {
                                $('#uploadifive').hide();
                                $('.uploadifive-queue-item').hide();

                                $('#uploadify').show();
                                $('.uploadify-queue-item').show();                                          
                                $('#uploadify').uploadify({
                                    'auto'              :   true,
                                    'fileSizeLimit'     :   "5GB",
                                    'formData'          :   { 'token' : '<?php echo $token; ?>' },
                                    'removeCompleted'   :   false,
                                    'queueSizeLimit'    :   0,
                                    'swf'               :   '/assets/addons/uploadify3/uploadify.swf',
                                    'uploader'          :   '/assets/transmitdocs_tempuploads/transmitdocs_moveFilesToServer.php',

                                    //'onCancel' doesn't work after file upload is completed, so need to create custom delete using onUploadSuccess

                                    'onUploadError'     :   function (file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                                                                alert("The file you selected ("+file.name+") was unable to be uploaded. Error was: "+errorMsg+" "+errorString);
                                                            },

                                    'onUploadStart'     :   function () {
                                                                document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').value = "Please wait...";
                                                                document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').disabled = 'disabled';
                                                            },

                                    'onUploadSuccess'   :   function (file) {
                                                                $(".uploadify-progress").fadeOut();

                                                                document.getElementById(file.id).style.position = "relative";

                                                                var cancelIcon = document.createElement("img");
                                                                cancelIcon.src = "/assets/icons/15x15/delete.png";
                                                                cancelIcon.alt = "Remove " + file.name + " from this transmittal";
                                                                cancelIcon.title = "Remove " + file.name + " from this transmittal";
                                                                cancelIcon.setAttribute ("onclick", "deleteFromUploadifyQueue(\"" + escape(file.id) + "\", \"" + escape(file.name) + "\");");
                                                                cancelIcon.style.position = "absolute";
                                                                cancelIcon.style.right = "0px";
                                                                cancelIcon.style.top = "0px";
                                                                cancelIcon.style.padding = "10px";
                                                                cancelIcon.style.cursor = "pointer";
                                                                cancelIcon.style.display = "none";
                                                                document.getElementById(file.id).appendChild(cancelIcon);

                                                                $(cancelIcon).fadeIn();
                                                            },

                                    'onQueueComplete'   :   function () {
                                                                document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').value = "Next >";
                                                                document.getElementById('subGoToStepFive').disabled = '';
                                                            }
                                });
                            }
});
```

});

Comment: Some details of any single file that fails might give some clues. Filename + ext? File size? Has your server been configured to support large files (5GB) too?

Comment: The files I'm testing the uploading with are PDFs, but I have tried other file types as well. The file names are just alpha-numeric. I haven't got the server configured to push 5GB yet, but the files I am testing with are all only a few hundred KB each.